# python lazy loading mode use the last value in the loop

Tags: python, scope, closures, lazy-loading

I want to set the class methods within a loop. 
Here is my example code:

```py
class A:
    pass

def gen_func(k):
    return classmethod(lambda cls: k)

for k in ('m1', 'm2'):
    def gen_func2(k):
        return classmethod(lambda cls: k)
    setattr(A, 'resolve_%s'%k, classmethod(lambda cls: k))  # print result is: m2, m2
    # setattr(A, 'resolve_%s'%k, classmethod((lambda: lambda cls: k)()))  # print result is: m2, m2

    # setattr(A, 'resolve_%s'%k, gen_func2(k)) # print result is: m1, m2
    # setattr(A, 'resolve_%s'%k, gen_func(k))  # print result is: m1, m2 #OK#

print(A.resolve_m1()) # expected print --> m1
print(A.resolve_m2()) # expected print --> m2
```

The result is expected print m1, m2.

But when I generate the method in the loop scopes, `k` always is the last one: `m2`.

I only know it is the reason of `scope`, if we use the function in the loop, it is executed lazily.

And I define `gen_func` outside of loop scopes, it worked.

But I want to know what the reason exactly is. 
How the code is executing in the computer in this situation.

I have tried to find the reason from books or website, but I have no idea about it.

Comment: Inside `(lambda: lambda cls: k)())` you are creating closure with `lambda`. This closure captures variable `k`, which at the end of loop is set to `m2`. When you call `resolve_m1()`, the closure has this variable `k` set to `m2`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thank you very much.
As of your said, I have found the result I wanted.

https://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2016/01/for-each-loops-should-define-new.html

Comment: I see you edited your post. `setattr(A, 'resolve_%s'%k, gen_func2(k))` will indeed return `m1, m2`, because you are creating a copy of `k`.

Comment: Yes, after I see your post and the article, I tried run the code again and find I wrote incorrectly for the `gen_func2` result.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @AndrejKesely

Now I know what it is, you can write with lambda:

[python link](https://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2016/01/for-each-loops-should-define-new.html)

```py
setattr(A, 'resolve_%s'%k, classmethod((lambda k: lambda cls: k)(k)))
```

Here is [the introduction of js closures](https://dmitryfrank.com/articles/js_closures), there are some pictures which is helpful to understand the process of closures:

> This concept of scope object is very different from, say, C or C++, where local variables are stored on stack. In JavaScript, scope objects are allocated in heap instead (or at least they behave like this), so they might stay allocated even if function already returned. More on that later.